# grep for pattern matching

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep

I have a problem with reading a pattern from a script file to another file. Basically the output from one file should be used as an input to the other script file.
The output from the maze_gen is an array of # and space symbols. the following example 5 7 represents the height and width of the output.

```bsh
if [`./maze_gen 5 7 | grep -E "[^# ]"` ]; then
        echo no
else 
        echo yes
fi
```

So here `maze_gen` is a file that produces a series of `#` symbols with spaces. 
This will receive as an input file that I am currently working on. There is something wrong with my code and I just can't check if the input has only `#` characters.

Comment: Could you add some example output from `maze_gen` to your question?

Comment: If you just want a has any bad lines / doesn't have any bad lines try adding `-m 1` [can use the return status] or add `-c` gives a count output.  But as @Natolio says - attach a sample please.

Comment: The code as written should produce a "command not found" error. Please make sure it matches what you think it should be (minding spaces in particular), and if it does, then paste it into https://shellcheck.net to see what's wrong

Comment: I'm sorry if English isn't your first language, but please try harder to *explain* what you are trying to do and what is happening.  "There is something wrong with my code" is not clear. … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: get rid of the backticks (\`). and you probably want to use grep's `-q` option to suppress normal output.  i.e. `if [ ./maze_gen 5 7 | grep -q -E "[^# ]" ]; then`

Comment: Note to reviewers: This is not a duplicate of the [bash: looping through characters not working](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/644463) question, IMHO. The data is stored in a variable in that question whereas here it's piped in.  These two issues therefore needs two different answers, even though the originating homework assignment (or whatever) may be identical.

Comment: @cas, you mean `if ./maze_gen | grep -q; then`. (roaima linked shellcheck.net earlier, an it also mentions that)

Comment: @ilkkachu yep, that's what i meant. i didn't edit the copy-paste properly, forgot to delete the [ and ].

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you want to test whether the output of `./maze_gen 5 7` contains characters other than spaces and hashes.

You can do that more efficiently using

```bsh
if ./maze_gen 5 7 | grep -q '[^ #]'
then
    echo no
else
    echo yes
fi
```

This does not actually *extract* the lines that matches the expression.  Instead `grep -q` exits as soon as the pattern matches and the exit-status of `grep` is used in the `if` statement to determine what branch to take (`echo no` or `echo yes`).

This is more efficient than what you seem to want to do because the `grep` utility stops processing its input as soon as the pattern matches, and the shell does not have to store the output from `grep` to use in a string comparison test.

Your code does not work since it contains syntax errors.  The `[` needs spaces around it.

Note also that `-E` enables extended regular expressions with some implementations of `grep`.  In your case here, this is not needed as the expression is a basic regular expression.

Comment: Hi Did I take the standard output from maze_gen correctly?